# How to select base-model samples in Random Forest based on some user-defined probability (Scikit-Learn)?

Tags: python, random, scikit-learn, random-forest, bootstrapping

How can I provide probabilities/weights to whether or not a sample will be chosen during Scikit-Learn's `RandomForest` base model creation?

For example, let's say I'm modeling 2 classes: 1) control; and 2) treatment.  I also have a separate grouping that has sub-categories for each of the samples (A, B, and C).

[image]

During base model creation, I want to preferentially draw the samples based on a probability (e.g., this is based on group_2 in the table).

**Can I achieve this with either the `sample_weights` or `class_weights` option? If not, is there another way to do this?**

For example, either this: `sample_weights={"sample_1":0.125, "sample_2":0.125, "sample_3":0.25, "sample_4":0.25, "sample_5":0.125, "sample_6":0.125}` or (probably less likely, but just in case) this `class_weights={"A":0.125, "B":0.75, "C":0.125}`.

**Are there any implementations that allow this? If not, how can I use class inheritance to build a custom `RandomForestClassifier` that can take in a `base_sample_probability` argument?**

---

**Extra Info:**

I've found some resources describing `class_weights` parameter in practice.  It appears to be used for imbalanced classes:

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26747/does-class-weight-solve-unbalanced-input-for-decision-tree

and here:

> This modification of random forest is referred to as Weighted Random Forest.

> Another approach to make random forest more suitable for learning from extremely imbalanced data follows the idea of cost sensitive learning. Since the RF classifier tends to be biased towards the majority class, we shall place a heavier penalty on misclassifying the minority class.

https://machinelearningmastery.com/bagging-and-random-forest-for-imbalanced-classification/

Comment: Do I understand that correctly: you wish to perform custom sampling on your train set based on one of the features rather than target? If so, using `sample_weight` should yield a similar result: it's just a list of weights with the same length as the train set.

Comment: When the base models (i.e., decision trees) are being generated and samples are randomly called for training the model, I'd like to specify a weight on those.  Is that what the `sample_weight` parameter does?

Comment: By weight, I mean a probability for each that it will be chosen.

Comment: @O.rka should the probabilities in the dictionary indicate the exact value for a given `sample_id`, or just the maximum that a specific `sample_id` can hold?

Comment: @O.rka Do I understand that correctly: you want to make bootstrap mechanism generate the sample for fitting decision trees not entirely randomly but randomly with weights (probabilities)?

Comment: @GonçaloPeres I would say the same functionality that np.random.choice has with their weight argument.

Comment: @BorisSilantev yes, that is what I’m trying to implement. My idea was to use np.random.choice with the weights and tandom_state arguments. The difficult part for me is the class inheritance for the random forest methods.

Answer (score 2):

The task you are trying to solve is setting the probabilities/weights for the bootstrap algorithm so that the samples with higher weights are passed more often to the decision trees.

Looking at the **`sklearn`** source code (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py) I can say that the **`sample_weight`** parameter of the **`fit()`** method doesn't impact the chances the samples will be passed to the decision tree. Instead, the value is passed to the decision tree's **`fit()`** method. **`class_weight`** parameter is used just to adjust (multiply) **`sample_weight`** and doesn't influence bootstrapping too.

The bootstrap algorithm itself is implemented in 2 lines of codes:

```
random_instance = check_random_state(random_state)
sample_indices = random_instance.randint(0, n_samples, n_samples_bootstrap)
```

So as we can see it is just pure random. Interesting fact: under the hood bootstrap doesn't drop any samples, it just adjusts **`sample_weight`** before it is passed to the decision tree **`fit()`** method, so that the "dropped" samples get the **`0`** weight.

Unfortunately, those 2 lines are not part of some **`RandomForestClassifier`** object method. It is a part of the global function **`_generate_sample_indices()`** which is called by another global function **`_parallel_build_trees()`**. And the latter is called by **`BaseForest.fit()`** method. So to solve the task we need to override all 3 functions/methods.

The implementation below is literally copy-paste from the sklearn source code with just some lines revised, but I can't see an easier way to solve the problem.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.tree._tree import DTYPE, DOUBLE
from sklearn.utils import check_random_state
from sklearn.utils.validation import _check_sample_weight
from sklearn.utils.multiclass import check_classification_targets, type_of_target
from sklearn.ensemble._forest import  _get_n_samples_bootstrap
from sklearn.exceptions import DataConversionWarning
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from warnings import catch_warnings, simplefilter, warn
from scipy.sparse import issparse
import numpy as np
def _generate_sample_indices_weighted_bootstrap(random_state, n_samples, n_samples_bootstrap, bootstrap_weight):
    """
    The version of sklearn.ensemble._forest._generate_sample_indices()
    with an extra parameter `bootstrap_weight`
    Private function used to _parallel_build_trees_weighted_bootstrap function."""
    
    if bootstrap_weight is None:
        p = np.ones(n_samples)
    else:
        p = np.array(bootstrap_weight)
    p /= p.sum()

    random_instance = check_random_state(random_state)
    # !!! The line below is overriden
    sample_indices = random_instance.choice(np.arange(n_samples), n_samples_bootstrap, True, p)

    return sample_indices

def _parallel_build_trees_weighted_bootstrap(
    tree,
    bootstrap,
    X,
    y,
    sample_weight,
    bootstrap_weight,
    tree_idx,
    n_trees,
    verbose=0,
    class_weight=None,
    n_samples_bootstrap=None,
):
    """
    The version of sklearn.ensemble._forest._parallel_build_trees()
    with an extra parameter `bootstrap_weight`
    Private function used to fit a single tree in parallel."""
    if verbose > 1:
        print("building tree %d of %d" % (tree_idx + 1, n_trees))

    if bootstrap:
        n_samples = X.shape[0]
        if sample_weight is None:
            curr_sample_weight = np.ones((n_samples,), dtype=np.float64)
        else:
            curr_sample_weight = sample_weight.copy()

        indices = _generate_sample_indices_weighted_bootstrap( # !!! This line overriden
            tree.random_state, n_samples, n_samples_bootstrap, bootstrap_weight
        )
        sample_counts = np.bincount(indices, minlength=n_samples)
        curr_sample_weight *= sample_counts

        if class_weight == "subsample":
            with catch_warnings():
                simplefilter("ignore", DeprecationWarning)
                curr_sample_weight *= compute_sample_weight("auto", y, indices=indices)
        elif class_weight == "balanced_subsample":
            curr_sample_weight *= compute_sample_weight("balanced", y, indices=indices)

        tree.fit(X, y, sample_weight=curr_sample_weight, check_input=False)
    else:
        tree.fit(X, y, sample_weight=sample_weight, check_input=False)

    return tree

class WeightedBootstrapRandomForestClassifier(RandomForestClassifier):
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        
    def fit(self, X, y, sample_weight=None, bootstrap_weight=None):
        """
        It is a version of sklearn.ensemble.BaseForest.fit() method
        with extra parameter `bootstrap_weight` which defines the
        probablity that the sample will be chosen during bootstrapping
        
        Build a forest of trees from the training set (X, y).
        Parameters
        ----------
        X : {array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_features)
            The training input samples. Internally, its dtype will be converted
            to ``dtype=np.float32``. If a sparse matrix is provided, it will be
            converted into a sparse ``csc_matrix``.
        y : array-like of shape (n_samples,) or (n_samples, n_outputs)
            The target values (class labels in classification, real numbers in
            regression).
        sample_weight : array-like of shape (n_samples,), default=None
            Sample weights. If None, then samples are equally weighted. Splits
            that would create child nodes with net zero or negative weight are
            ignored while searching for a split in each node. In the case of
            classification, splits are also ignored if they would result in any
            single class carrying a negative weight in either child node.
        bootstrap_weight : array-like of shape (n_samples,), default=None
            Sample-wise weights. If None, then samples are equally weighted.
            The weights determine the probability that the sample will be selected
            while bootstrapping.
        Returns
        -------
        self : object
            Fitted estimator.
        """

        # Validate or convert input data
        if issparse(y):
            raise ValueError("sparse multilabel-indicator for y is not supported.")
        if sample_weight is not None:
            sample_weight = _check_sample_weight(sample_weight, X)

        if issparse(X):
            # Pre-sort indices to avoid that each individual tree of the
            # ensemble sorts the indices.
            X.sort_indices()

        y = np.atleast_1d(y)
        if y.ndim == 2 and y.shape[1] == 1:
            warn(
                "A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was"
                " expected. Please change the shape of y to "
                "(n_samples,), for example using ravel().",
                DataConversionWarning,
                stacklevel=2,
            )

        if y.ndim == 1:
            # reshape is necessary to preserve the data contiguity against vs
            # [:, np.newaxis] that does not.
            y = np.reshape(y, (-1, 1))

        if self.criterion == "poisson":
            if np.any(y < 0):
                raise ValueError(
                    "Some value(s) of y are negative which is "
                    "not allowed for Poisson regression."
                )
            if np.sum(y) <= 0:
                raise ValueError(
                    "Sum of y is not strictly positive which "
                    "is necessary for Poisson regression."
                )

        self.n_outputs_ = y.shape[1]

        y, expanded_class_weight = self._validate_y_class_weight(y)

        if getattr(y, "dtype", None) != DOUBLE or not y.flags.contiguous:
            y = np.ascontiguousarray(y, dtype=DOUBLE)

        if expanded_class_weight is not None:
            if sample_weight is not None:
                sample_weight = sample_weight * expanded_class_weight
            else:
                sample_weight = expanded_class_weight

        if not self.bootstrap and self.max_samples is not None:
            raise ValueError(
                "`max_sample` cannot be set if `bootstrap=False`. "
                "Either switch to `bootstrap=True` or set "
                "`max_sample=None`."
            )
        elif self.bootstrap:
            n_samples_bootstrap = _get_n_samples_bootstrap(
                n_samples=X.shape[0], max_samples=self.max_samples
            )
        else:
            n_samples_bootstrap = None

        self._validate_estimator()
        if isinstance(self, (RandomForestRegressor)):
            # TODO(1.3): Remove "auto"
            if self.max_features == "auto":
                warn(
                    "`max_features='auto'` has been deprecated in 1.1 "
                    "and will be removed in 1.3. To keep the past behaviour, "
                    "explicitly set `max_features=1.0` or remove this "
                    "parameter as it is also the default value for "
                    "RandomForestRegressors and ExtraTreesRegressors.",
                    FutureWarning,
                )
        elif isinstance(self, (RandomForestClassifier)):
            # TODO(1.3): Remove "auto"
            if self.max_features == "auto":
                warn(
                    "`max_features='auto'` has been deprecated in 1.1 "
                    "and will be removed in 1.3. To keep the past behaviour, "
                    "explicitly set `max_features='sqrt'` or remove this "
                    "parameter as it is also the default value for "
                    "RandomForestClassifiers and ExtraTreesClassifiers.",
                    FutureWarning,
                )

        if not self.bootstrap and self.oob_score:
            raise ValueError("Out of bag estimation only available if bootstrap=True")

        random_state = check_random_state(self.random_state)

        if not self.warm_start or not hasattr(self, "estimators_"):
            # Free allocated memory, if any
            self.estimators_ = []

        n_more_estimators = self.n_estimators - len(self.estimators_)

        if n_more_estimators < 0:
            raise ValueError(
                "n_estimators=%d must be larger or equal to "
                "len(estimators_)=%d when warm_start==True"
                % (self.n_estimators, len(self.estimators_))
            )

        elif n_more_estimators == 0:
            warn(
                "Warm-start fitting without increasing n_estimators does not "
                "fit new trees."
            )
        else:
            if self.warm_start and len(self.estimators_) > 0:
                # We draw from the random state to get the random state we
                # would have got if we hadn't used a warm_start.
                random_state.randint(MAX_INT, size=len(self.estimators_))

            trees = [
                self._make_estimator(append=False, random_state=random_state)
                for i in range(n_more_estimators)
            ]

            # Parallel loop: we prefer the threading backend as the Cython code
            # for fitting the trees is internally releasing the Python GIL
            # making threading more efficient than multiprocessing in
            # that case. However, for joblib 0.12+ we respect any
            # parallel_backend contexts set at a higher level,
            # since correctness does not rely on using threads.
            trees = Parallel(
                n_jobs=self.n_jobs,
                verbose=self.verbose,
                prefer="threads",
            )(
                delayed(_parallel_build_trees_weighted_bootstrap)( # !!! This line overriden
                    t,
                    self.bootstrap,
                    X,
                    y,
                    sample_weight,
                    bootstrap_weight,
                    i,
                    len(trees),
                    verbose=self.verbose,
                    class_weight=self.class_weight,
                    n_samples_bootstrap=n_samples_bootstrap,
                )
                for i, t in enumerate(trees)
            )

            # Collect newly grown trees
            self.estimators_.extend(trees)

        if self.oob_score:
            y_type = type_of_target(y)
            if y_type in ("multiclass-multioutput", "unknown"):
                # FIXME: we could consider to support multiclass-multioutput if
                # we introduce or reuse a constructor parameter (e.g.
                # oob_score) allowing our user to pass a callable defining the
                # scoring strategy on OOB sample.
                raise ValueError(
                    "The type of target cannot be used to compute OOB "
                    f"estimates. Got {y_type} while only the following are "
                    "supported: continuous, continuous-multioutput, binary, "
                    "multiclass, multilabel-indicator."
                )
            self._set_oob_score_and_attributes(X, y)

        # Decapsulate classes_ attributes
        if hasattr(self, "classes_") and self.n_outputs_ == 1:
            self.n_classes_ = self.n_classes_[0]
            self.classes_ = self.classes_[0]

        return self
```

So when it is done you can train the model like this:

```
y = np.random.randint(0, 2, 1000)
bootstrap_weight = np.ones(1000)
bootstrap_weight[:500] = 2
X = np.random.random((1000,3)) + 0.01 * y[:, np.newaxis] * bootstrap_weight[:, np.newaxis]
model = WeightedBootstrapRandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10)
model.fit(X, y, bootstrap_weight=bootstrap_weight)
```

Comment: This is an incredible explanation.  Thank you so much for breaking down not only what the sample weights and class weights parameters do but how the actual randomforest bootstrapping works with nested functions.  I sincerely appreciate the effort you put it in to not only implementing but teaching as well.